# how to concatenate video files in moviepy when all video file paths are written in a list

Tags: python, moviepy

im writing a code which takes inputs from user to get paths of video files the user want to concatenate. now if the user has 5 videos which they want to concatenate and make one file out of them, my program does a good job getting all the videofile paths and stores them in a list. but the issue is I cant concatenate them using moviepy while they are in a list.
this is the code

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
listofpath=[]
no_vid = int(input('enter no of vid u wanna compile:  '))
for i in range(no_vid):
    vidpath = input('enter path to the files u wanna compile:  ')
    listofpath.append(vidpath)
print(listofpath)

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([listofpath])
final_clip.write_videofile("E:\python_work\downloaded\my_concatenation.mp4")
```

Comment: Change `listofpath.append(vidpath)` to listofpath.append(VideoFileClip(vidpath))` should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

listofpath=[]
no_vid = int(input('enter no of vid u wanna compile:  '))
for i in range(no_vid):
    vidpath = input('enter path to the files u wanna compile:  ')
    listofpath.append(vidpath)
print(listofpath)
```

Create a list of VideoFileClip objects

```
clips = [VideoFileClip(file) for file in listofpath]
```

Concatenate the clips

```
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
```

Then write the video

```
final_clip.write_videofile("E:\python_work\downloaded\my_concatenation.mp4")
```